# .NET - Problem with printing

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Presently I am having a problem with printing in C#.
I have a pre-printed bill, and I need to print values into some
specific points of that bill.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please describe what you are doing, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and why you think what happens is a problem.

Comment: BTW, C# has no ability to print.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your need correctly, you can create a PDF file using [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) with the proper values in the specific locations you need, and then print it on your pre-print bill.

You can also try using the [XPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772.aspx) documents, there are some good controls to help you accomplish this task.

---

If your going the iTextSharp way, the `SetAbsolutePosition` function is your friend. See the documentation on how to absolute positioning of elements in the PDF file.

Comment: Hello
I think you got my problem correctly. Now I am going to try it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a standard reporting tool, this will have a visual interface to help lay things out?

Comment: No I cant use those. Because I need to dynamically change my printing points. Oh I forget to mention that my customer can set his printing points location dynamically.

Thanks.